# Automatically set number in vim without modifying vimrc because of limited permission

Tags: vim, csh

I don't have permission to modify vimrc, but I really need to view the line numbers every time. Is there an alternative way to do the following without modifying the vimrc file?

```
:set number
```

Plus, I have a system cshrc file which is modifiable. Can I add similar syntax in this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own vim configuration file, and then create an alias for `vim` to use that file instead of `.vimrc`:

```
vim .vimrc-cdnszip
```

Put the following contents into this file:

```
source /etc/vim/vimrc
source ~/.vimrc

set number

" any additional confiuguration you might want...
```

Then alias `vim` to `vim -u ~/.vimrc-cdnszip` in your `cshrc` file. I've never used `csh` so I don't know how aliases work there, but in `bash` this would work:

```
alias vim="vim -u ~/.vimrc-cdnszip"
```

Comment: I wonder if the OP knows that using `~/.vimrc` is possible, i.e. if he tried to modify a system `vimrc` file somewhere... It's not clear.

Comment: @Kusalananda you're right, I hadn't even considered that. I've been in such a situation though - I shared a root account with several other people on a server, and we had conflicting ideas on how vim should be configured. So I was technically able to modify `~/.vimrc`, but I didn't want to. I used the solution I posted to have my own configuration :)